# Query to find out solution for finding difference rows of two table

Tags: mysql

```
TableA (master data)       (Productcode, Rate)
TableB (Transaction data)  (Productcode, Rate, Qty)
```

I want to see whole row which is rate alter while selling (Transaction data TableB)

Example:

TableA (master data)

```
Productcode        Rate 
1000               50      
2000               100    
3000               200
```

TableB  (Transaction data)

```
Productcode        Rate 
1000               50      
2000               90   
3000               200
```

Expected result:

TableB

```
Productcode        Rate    
2000               90
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not how we roll

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows that have same `ProductCode` with different rate you need just this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB 
WHERE TableB.Rate <> (SELECT TableA.Rate FROM TableA WHERE TableA.ProductCode = TableB.ProductCode)
```

Or

```
SELECT TableB* 
FROM TableB INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.ProductCode = TableA.ProductCode
WHERE TableB.Rate <> TableA.Rate
```

Comment: Thank you, absolutely Right Mistake from my side

Comment: If you dont mind Give me a solution if there is some more condition like transaction rate + or - 10% if reach rate of master data then no need to show    ----   Eg: TableB (Transaction data) ---- 
Productcode ----       Rate 
1000         ----              50      
2000         ----              90   +/- 10%
3000         ----             200                                                                          Expected result:

TableB

Productcode      ----    Rate    
2000                  ----     90      81-99 --  less or add 10%(not reaching tableA rate [master data]

Comment: @mohammed for any condition just change (`TableB.Rate <> TableA.Rate`) to your own condition like (`TebleB.Rate Between TableA.Rate*0.9 And TableA.Rate*1.1` => +/-10%)